# Selenium RC single window - how to maximize client frame

Tags: selenium

I am testing an application to test that must run in Selenium's single window mode. Multi window mode is not an option.

The problem is Selenium's frame takes a big chunk of the browser window.

How can I have the application frame expand to fill the browser window (and/or shrink the selenium part)?

Test code is in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of using Selenium.RunScript() to run some JavaScript code that adjusts the dimensions of each frame, you can't.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the selenium API doc:

> window_maximize(self, windowName)

Resize window to take up the entire screen

'windowName' is name of the window to be enlarged

Comment: Selenium and the AUT appear in the _same_ window as separate frames. I need to max the AUT frame and minimize the Selenium frame.